# how to detect image/video not exist anymore from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I need embed image/video from facebook on my website.
On implemented, how i can detect if image/video not exist anymore or in private mode? so in this condition, image/video will be hidden.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution, may be we can try header responses if it is 200 means the content exists? Any clue..

Comment: When you make an API request for any object that either doesn’t exist (any more), or that is not visible with the access token used, you will get a response with error code 100 and a message saying “Unsupported get request. […]”

Comment: i just show image/video with embed facebook url. I want control it in php, if image/video not exist or in private, not error embed but i can control to hide it from my website.